# Where to put native code for push notifications with new Meteor Mobile platform

Tags: meteor

After reviewing the new Mobile features with latest 1.0 version of Meteor, I'm not seeing where I would modify the Cordova code to add custom capabilities. For instance, I want to implement push notifications for my application on both iOS and Android.  In both cases I would need to write some native code so that I could get devices registered and accept push notification messages.

Currently, I'm using [MeteorRider](https://github.com/zeroasterisk/MeteorRider) to accomplish this and it works great. I have 3 separate projects for Meteor, Android and iOS.  In the latter 2, I put the native code there necessary to accomplish this. One thing is for certain, you have to update the bootstrap classes in Cordova to allow registrations to work.

In Meteor 1.0, how would I go about accomplishing this with the out-of-the-box mobile feature?

Here's the objective-C code for accepting push notification registration responses that is required in Cordova's AppDelegate:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSLog( @"Device token is: %@", deviceToken);

    // Convert to string that can be stored in DB
    NSString *regId = [[deviceToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    regId = [regId stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    regId = [regId stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    [[ApplePushNotificationService sharedInstance] application:application uploadDeviceToken:regId];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***TL;DR : The cordova project is in the `.meteor/local/cordova-build` subfolder.***

The default `AppDelegate.m` gets created in the `.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/***YOUR_APP_NAME***/Classes` subfolder.

If you add a top-level folder called `cordova-build-override` to your meteor project, the directory tree that it contains will be added to the `.meteor/local/cordova-build` folder just before the build and compilation step.

So, put your custom AppDelegate.m in a new folder called `cordova-build-override/platforms/ios/***YOUR_APP_NAME***/Classes` .

```sh
mkdir -p cordova-build-override/platforms/ios/foo/Classes
cp .meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/foo/Classes/AppDelegate.m cordova-build-override/platforms/ios/foo/Classes
```

---

The [Meteor-Cordova integration page on the GitHub Meteor wiki](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration) is the best place (so far) to find the details of cordova development with meteor.

You put your cordova-specific code in plain javascript. It's best not to modify the native code if at all possible; instead, see if you can write your own cordova plugin and use it from your meteor app. [The cordova PushPlugin plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) might do what you're looking for, but if not, you can use it as a reference.

---

This example below will create a new iOS app that uses a non-meteor cordova plugin, from scratch.

***NOTE:*** *This is a bare minimum example. Look at the [meteor cordova camera plugin](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/tree/master/packages/mdg:camera) for a full example. The code below is based on that plugin.*

```sh
# create a meteor app foo
meteor create foo
cd foo
# add the iOS cordova platform
meteor add-platform ios

# create a new meteor package, foo-camera.
# NOTE: You need to substitute your own meteor.com developer ID here
meteor create --package your_meteor_developer_id:foo-camera
```

Now, edit the `packages/your_meteor_developer_id:foo-camera/package.js` file to add the following:

```js
// Add the camera cordova plugin at version 0.3.3

Cordova.depends({
    'org.apache.cordova.camera': '0.3.3'
});
```

> **EDIT 1**: This causes the plugin to be downloaded to your cordova plugins folder. 
>   You can refer to a git tarball instead of a version number e.g. :
>
> ```js
> Cordova.depends({
>   'com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect': 'https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tarball/0e61babb65bc1716b957b6294c7fdef3ce6ace79'
> });
> ```
>
> [source: meteor cordova wiki](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration)

While we're at it, limit our code to run only on the client, and export our FooCamera object so it can be used in the rest of our meteor javascript:

```js
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.0');
  api.export('FooCamera');
  api.addFiles('your_meteor_developer_id:foo-camera.js','client');
});
```

> ***Edit 2***:
>   If your cordova plugin needs special configuration, you can define this in your meteor app's
>   [mobile configuration file](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mobileconfigjs). It will get copied into 
>   your app's config.xml .
>
> E.g.
>
> ```js
> // ===== mobile-config.js ======
> // Set PhoneGap/Cordova preferences
> App.setPreference('SOME_SPECIFIC_PLUGIN_KEY','SOME_SPECIFIC_PLUGIN_VAL');
> ```
>
> Your app's config.xml will then eventually result in the following:
>
> ```xml
>   <preference name="SOME_SPECIFIC_PLUGIN_KEY" value="SOME_SPECIFIC_PLUGIN_VAL"/>
> ```

Next, edit the JavaScript file in your package ( `packages/your_meteor_developer_id:foo-camera/your_meteor_developer_id:foo-camera.js` ) to expose the cordova functionality in a meteor-like manner. Use the [official meteor mobile package examples](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages) as a reference.

(the code below is stolen shamelessly from the [meteor github repo](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/tree/master/packages/mdg:camera) ) :

```js
FooCamera = {};

FooCamera.getPicture = function (options, callback) {
  // if options are not passed
  if (! callback) {
    callback = options;
    options = {};
  }

  var success = function (data) {
    callback(null, "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data);
  };

  var failure = function (error) {
    callback(new Meteor.Error("cordovaError", error));
  };

  // call the cordova plugin here, and pass the result to our callback.
  navigator.camera.getPicture(success, failure, 
    _.extend(options, {
      quality: options.quality || 49,
      targetWidth: options.width || 640,
      targetHeight: options.height || 480,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
    })
  );
};
```

Now, add your new (local) package to your meteor app.

```sh
meteor add your_meteor_developer_id:foo-camera
```

Edit your application's main HTML and JS to use your new meteor package.

In your `foo.html` , replace the hello template with this:

```html
<template name="hello">
  <button>Take a Photo</button>

  {{#if photo}}
    <div>
      <img src={{photo}} />
    </div>
  {{/if}}  
</template>
```

In your `foo.js` , replace the button click event handler with this:

```js
  Template.hello.helpers({
    photo: function () {
      return Session.get("photo");
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      var cameraOptions = {
        width: 800,
        height: 600
      };

      FooCamera.getPicture(cameraOptions, function (error, data) {
        Session.set("photo", data);
      });
    }
  });
```

Now, plug your device in, make sure it's on the same network as your computer, and start both the meteor server and the ios app.

```sh
meteor run ios-device
# If you want to just use the emulator, use the following instead.
# but of course the camera won't work on the emulator.
#meteor run ios
```

XCode will open. You may need to set up your certificates and provisioning profiles before running your app (from XCode).

In another terminal, tail the logs:

```
tail -f .meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
```

Finally, publish your excellent meteor cordova plugin so that everyone else can use it. Edit package.js [as per the meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/packagejs). Then:

```
cd packages/your_meteor_developer_id\:foo-camera
meteor publish
```

Comment: This is really great and thank you for the time you put into this! However, in the case of push notifications I have supporting push notifications .m/.h files in my plugins directory and have my push notification plugin defined in my config.xml. I imagine I could pull those files under the `cordova-build-override` directory but then how do reference them from either a new package or existing code?

Comment: I've made a couple of edits to better illustrate this. 

In the above code, ```navigator.camera.getPicture(...)``` is the call that uses the cordova plugin. I've wrapped it in the package which gets used by the client, where ```FooCamera.getPicture(...)``` is called.

The ```Cordova.depends(...)``` in your ```package.js``` will put the specified plugin into your plugins directory. 

The ```mobile-config.js``` file is where you put your app preferences for the plugin.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you suggesting the only way to get a non-Cordova registered plugin into your project is to reference it from GitHub? The Meteor docs seem to suggest this as well but I suppose it enforces better reuse. Regardless, I accepted your excellent answer!

Comment: Yes you need to point it to a tarball URL (it doesn't have to be github). You also need the SHA1 at the end of the URL. From looking at the meteor source, it appears that the regular expression is `/^https?:\/\/.*[0-9a-f]{40}/`. So you could put your own cordova plugin tarball on any website. I tested it with this URL: `
http://localhost:8383/cordovaCameraApp/cordova-plugin-camera-master.tgz#7a39301f959308e699ca95cb2f94a53246ace77c` . Use the `shasum` command to get the SHA.